# How to get Android.Telephony.PhoneState when screen is off?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a question pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385372/phonestatelistener-onsignalstrengthschanged-stops-being-called-in-service), but it was asked 6 years ago I thought that maybe something has chnaged.

Basically I want no notify user when signal is lost. I've implemented class that inherits from `PhoneStateListener` and `OnServiceStateChanged` method in it. Also I have a service that runs in background and listens to changes. Everything works fine as long, as screen is on.

But apparently Android do not invoke `OnServiceStateChanged` when screen is off. Is there any way to get `Android.Telephony.PhoneState` directly from service or maybe some other workaround?

My code so far is below:

[PhoneStateListener](https://pastebin.com/MPqzkJQX)

[Service](https://pastebin.com/nG0iyb5w)

Comment: Post your this code **Everything works fine as long, as screen is on**.

Comment: @VicJordan, updated

Answer (score 0):

Try to create BroadcastReciever Class

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

and change the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I think you required following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

After creating Broadcast Receiver class insert following code snippet in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <receiver android:name="//BroadcastReceiver Class Name" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE">

            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

`AndroidManifest.xml` file, I think you required following permission

```
<uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
            tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

creating Broadcast Receiver class in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <receiver android:name=".services.Blocker">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Blocker.java**

```
public class Blocker extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     /* write your code here */
    }
}
```